# onmouse event does not work online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one problem. On mouse move event does not work online, but on my localhost it work correct..

```
`<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-11-11-113319" src="img/main_map.fw.png"   usemap="#image-maps-2014-11-11-113319" alt="" />`
```

`<map name="image-maps-2014-11-11-113319" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-11-11-113319">`

`<area shape="rect" coords="791,1121,793,1123" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" />`

<`area  alt="" title="BANADIR"  shape="poly" coords="349,750.6666870117188,355,739.6666870117188,363,737.6666870117188,372,739.6666870117188" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-11-11-113319').src= 'img/sect/banadir.jpg';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-11-11-113319').src= 'img/main_map.fw.png';"  />`

`</map>`

That is my code... Can you help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Since you are looking for `img/sect/banadir.jpg` - does that file exist online?

Comment: any console errors in the browser?

Comment: Yaah! all images are online and I double check the image path is fine..

Comment: btw - you should separate your javascript from your html

Comment: Can you post the rest of your related HTML. You can also inspect the code and see if the image source has changed and there are no errors in console

Comment: ok let me post all of it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `<area>` is but if you change it to `<textarea>` it seems to work fine

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gsxLdzc/1/)

Comment: I think they mean something like 

<map><area></area></map>

Comment: May be because of the lack of context if you are nested under <map>, more code would be helpful

Comment: the problem the OP is complaining I guess is the lack of showing images on mouse events.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area it's for image maps

Comment: Yes, i see this now.  Thank you. However, OP didn't give context of what is broken.

Comment: Scroll the code to the right, I assume the js is not working for onmouseover. I would leave your answer as a comment as it does not really answers the question

Comment: is area of a map.. if you look at **coords** I set specific coordinates that when you move your mouse over those coordinates image will change